# Restart audio and animation on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, audio, click

Please look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rabelais/zDu2s/1/

There are three bars that when clicked play/pause music. The divs also animate on click.

When the animation is complete a refresh button appears and resets the animation width to 0.

My question is how can I make the song and animation restart when the refresh button is clicked on.

I am only displaying a small amount of the code below as there is so much and one really ned to look at the fiddle above to see all the code.

```
var $sounds = $('.sound'),
$bars = $('#sound-bars .bars');
$bars.click(function () {
var $this = $(this),
    $target = $($this.data('target')),
    target = $target[0];
$bars.not(this).removeClass('playing');
$sounds.not($target).each(function () {
    this.pause();
});

$this.toggleClass('playing');
if ($this.hasClass('playing')) {
    target.play();
} else {
    target.pause();
}
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restart the audio over,  you can use `currentTime` and set it to 0. As @Robb suggested, you can also trigger the click of the specific bar to start the animation over. You will also need to remove the `playing` and `active` classes from the bar.

```
$('#refresh-1').click(function () {
   $('.alt0').width(0);
   $('.alt0').stop();
   $(this).hide();
   $('#sound-1')[0].pause();
   $('#sound-1')[0].currentTime = 0;
   $('#one').removeClass('active playing');
   $('#one').click();
})
```

I assume that the animation of the bar is supposed to show the current position of the audio track against the total duration. You can use the Audio API funciton `duration` to get the total duration (in seconds) of the audio file, to which you can then use in the duration of the animation like so:

```
var $this = $(this),
    $target = $($this.data('target')),
    target = $target[0];
$('.alt0').animate({ //start animation
   width: $(this).width()
}, target.duration * 1000, "linear", function () {
   $("#refresh-1").show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, any chance you could show me this working on a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to trigger a click event within the refresh buttons click event.

```
$("#refresh-1").click(function () {
    $(".alt0").width(0);
    $("#one").removeClass('active');
    $("#one").trigger("click");
    $(this).hide();
})
```

You may have to modify the refresh's code to clear any classes that prevent immediately playing the sound/animation again. I was able to with `.removeClass('active')`